# In R, how can I make the branches of a classification tree not overlap in a plot?

Tags: r, tree, plot

I have a tree with a lot of branches. Here is my code to plot the tree. The problem is that the labels overlap each other, specially towards the bottom of the tree. Is there any way to plot the tree so that the labels don't overlap?

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(prunedTree, type=c("uniform"))
text(prunedTree)
```

Note--I used "type=c("uniform"))" because it helped readability the lower branches. Also, prunedTree is the class "tree" from the tree package.

Here's a sample of what is being produced currently.

[image]

EDIT: Code to fully reproduce the issue.

```
load(url("https://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/dataanalysis/samsungData.rda"))
samsungData$subject <- factor(samsungData$subject)
samsungData$activity <- factor(samsungData$activity)
samsungData <- samsungData[, !c(duplicated(names(samsungData)))]
names(samsungData) <- gsub("[.]", "", names(samsungData))
samsungData <- data.frame(samsungData)
trainDF <- samsungData[samsungData$subject %in% c(1,3,5,6),]
tree1 <- tree(activity ~ ., data=trainDF)
plot(tree1)
text(tree1)
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example for us to work with? (And is there any reason you're using **tree** rather than **rpart**?)

Comment: @joran Regarding your second question, because I didn't know it existed or why I would prefer it. I'll post some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to joran indications listed above, you can play with parameters:

- `srt` to rtotate your text.
- give different colors for text

For example :

```
plot(tree1)
text(tree1,col=rainbow(5)[1:25],srt=85,cex=0.8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have several general options:

1. Use a wider graphics device. (i.e. `png(...,width = 1200,height = ...)`)
2. Shrink the text using `cex = 0.5` (or smaller)
3. Use more concise column (i.e. variable) names
4. Some combination of the previous three.

I thought I could get `text.tree` to use fewer significant digits in labeling the splits, but I can't seem to do that. **rpart** appears to use only 4 digits by default, so that would save you some space as well.